# Разрешение на подключение бд к сайту

Tags: база-данных

Здравствуйте. Как настроить файл фейврола http://rghost.ru/35781010 по сайт epsilion-w.ru  для доступа сайта к бд. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: укажите какие сервисы крутятся на машине (апач, база данных - какая именно, какие настройки сервисов, по каким портам работают) - скажем как настроить файерволл

Answer (score 1):

```
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPTiptables -t filter -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Тут что-то одно нужно выкинуть, скорее dport, если это не DNS сервер. А что именно не получается? БД какая?

Comment: мда... и что получиться если выкинуть указание порта? разрешение всего трафика udp? а если выкинуть упоминание про udp то разрешение всем и всего? гениально!

Answer (score 0):

хм... Тут вроде как нужно использовать tcp протокол, а не udp.